# Mitzvah of walking in Eretz Israel

Tags: eretz-yisrael, mitzvah

I heard that every 4 or 2 amot walked in Eretz Israel is a mitzvah. Is this true? If it is, from where do we learn this?

Answer (score 6):

The *gemara* in *[Ketubot daf 111a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%90)* learns it from the *passuk* in **Isaiah** (chapter 42, verse 5):

> ורוח להולכים בה א"ר ירמיה בר אבא א"ר יוחנן כל המהלך ארבע אמות בארץ ישראל מובטח לו שהוא בן העולם הבא
>
> **And spirit to them that walk therein [teaches]**, said R. Jeremiah b. Abba in the name of R. Johanan, that whoever walks four cubits in the Land of Israel is assured of a place in the world to come.

This however does not mean that it is an actual official **mitzvah**, just that it's a good thing. Some would deem this enough to call it a *"mitzvah"*.

Comment: Any source that *every* 4 cubits is a mitzvah? This seems to say just the initial 4 cubits.

Comment: See also Rambam [Hilchot Melachim 5:11](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.5.11) where he states this as fact. However Rambam does not count "walking four amot in Israel" as one of his 613 mitzvot in sefer hamitzvot.

Comment: @LN6595 No such source that I know of, however it is said of Rabbi Yosef Chaim Sonnenfeld that he would walk 4 *different* cubits every day for this reason.

Comment: @Bachrach44 I would be medayek that the Rambam says "halach ba" and not "holeich ba" to mean that only the initial 4 cubits walked per lifetime? since the last sin? effects Kapparah. But I really am not sure.